# Can you please explain the difference between code below

Tags: java

How its output will come? I have doubt object for which class is created in both cases. I am new in java so please explain the object instantiation process briefly.
In this program I expect the output as 150, but ans in=s 90.
How methods and data variables access difference?

program 1:

```
class Bike
{
    int speedlimit=90;
}
class Honda3 extends Bike
{
    int speedlimit=150;
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Bike obj=new Honda3();
        System.out.println(obj.speedlimit);//90
    }
}
```

program 2:

```
class Bike
{
    int speedlimit=90;
    void display()
    { 
        System.out.println(speedlimit);
    }
}
class Honda3 extends Bike
{
    int speedlimit=150;
    void display()
    {
        System.out.println(speedlimit);
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Bike obj=new Honda3();
        obj.display();
    }
}
```

Explain diff between these two codes.
    In program 1, object is created for `Honda3` and is assigned to obj of type `Bike`. I didn't understand how super class method is executed?

Comment: Fields are not polymorphic. When you access `obj.speedlimit` on a reference to a `Bike`, you get `Bike.speedlimit`, irrespective of whether there is a field called `speedlimit` on the concrete subclass of `Bike`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a subclass declares a method with the same signature (method name + parameter types) as a method in the base class, the base class method is **overridden**.

This means that the subclass method is always called for objects of the subclass, even if the variable used to make the call is declared as the base class.

---

When a subclass declares a field with the same name as a field in the base class, the base class field is **hidden**, but they both still exist and can have different values.

Code in the base class will access the field in the base class.

Code in the subclass will access the field in the subclass. The field in the base class has been hidden, but can be accessed by qualifying with `super.`.

Code outside the classes will access the field that is visible to the compiler, i.e. the field from the class of the variable used to access the field.

---

So, when `Bike obj = new Honda3()` is used, you get:

- `obj.display()` will call the `Honda3.display()` method.
- `obj.speedlimit` will access the `Bike.speedlimit` field.

---

For these reasons, field *hiding* is a **big NO, NO!**
Don't do it. The code becomes obscure and may not behave as you think it should.

Any good IDE will warn you if you do it.

Methods that *override* base class methods should always be annotated with `@Override`. The compiler will verify that the method actually does override a base class method, ensuring that you didn't mess up the method signature.

Any good IDE will warn you if you don't annotate, to ensure that you don't accidentally override a base class method when you didn't intend to do so.

Answer (score 0):

> i didn't understand how super class method is executed??

You can't call the super class's implementation of an overridden method.  This is by design. You shouldn't give two methods the same name and have one override the other if they have different purposes.

```
class Bike {
   int speedlimit=90;
   void display() { 
        System.out.println(speedlimit);
   }
}

class Honda3 extends Bike {
     int overdriveSpeedlimit=150;
     void displayOverdrive() {
          System.out.println(overdriveSpeedlimit);
     }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Honda3 honda= new Honda3();
    honda.displayOverdrive();
    Bike obj = honda;
    obj.display();
}
```